# Webrequest and stream, does not read between [ ] c#

Tags: c#, json, xbmc

I am trying to read a json string from a webrequest.
I use the HttpWebRequest because the server need authentication.

I can read the answer string, except the data between the [ ].

the answer should look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [{
        "playerid": 0,
        "type": "video"
    }]
}
```

but only looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": []
}
```

The json is generated by Kodi/xbmc

What am I doing wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string Url = @" http://192.168.1.118:8080/jsonrpc?request={""jsonrpc"": ""2.0"", ""method"": ""Player.GetActivePlayers"", ""id"": 1} ";

    string credentials = "user:passwd";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials)));
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that request really returns the JSON you expect, i.e `{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"playerid":0,"type":"video"}]}`? Because there is no reason `StreamReader` would modify it.

Comment: Yes, if i type the same url in my webbrowser, i got that answer.

Comment: If you typed it in your browser, how did you send the authorization header? Perhaps you have a bad header?

Comment: No, my browser asks for it in a separate popup box.